# Config::LoadFile: Found incorrect option 'My.Conf' in config file

Tags: azerothcore

I'm working on a new conf `My.Conf` and I get these 2 errors, one on the very start of the `worldserver`:

```
azerothcore-wotlk/cmake-build-relwithdebinfo/src/server/worldserver/worldserver
> Config::LoadFile: Found incorrect option 'My.Conf' in config file 'azerothcore-wotlk/env/dist/etc/worldserver.conf'. Skip
```

the other one later on when it stops running:

```
> Config: Missing property Rate.MissChanceMultiplier.TargetCreature in all config files, at least the .dist file must contain: "My.Conf = 1"
```

This seems crazy as they are one the opposite of the other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the config was present in `worldserver.conf` **but not in** `worldserver.conf.dist`.

Just make sure your config is present on **both files**.